# Automatically generate missing images

Tags: images

I'd like to auto-generate images, or rather image sizes, in old posts where the size is currently missing.

Specifically I'm hoping to generate sizes on the fly when a specific (old) image size is missing, but the original image is still in tact.

**Background:** A while back I cleaned house with images on a site in hopes of normalizing my image sizes. Totally forgetting about the various older auto-generated images that were soft-cropped. So now there are a couple hundred old images that aren't displaying.

**Details:** I did regenerate all the sizes when the house cleaning took place.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to install, or if it is available on your server, I would recommend using [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/). It has [a command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/regenerate/) to regenerate the media:

```sh
wp media regenerate --only-missing
```

If not, you can try a plugin such as [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

Good luck!

Comment: Eh, I couldn't think of a better way to word the question.
But I was hoping to find a way to auto-generate a specific size when a page loads and the specific size is missing, but the original is in tact.

The problem arose from me getting rid of soft-cropped sizes, so the originals have dimensions that are all over the place. :/

Answer (score 0):

If the images are all referred to by URLs embedded in post content, then you could just upload the missing files from an old backup.